# “Binary was not built with debug information” spam on Visual Studio 2008 when running my program

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

When I compile/run my C++ program in visual studio, it keeps spamming these lines maybe 10 times a second:

```
'test.exe': Loaded '(...).dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'test.exe': Unloaded '(...).dll'
'test.exe': Loaded '(...).dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'test.exe': Unloaded '(...).dll'
'test.exe': Loaded '(...).dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'test.exe': Unloaded '(...).dll'
'test.exe': Loaded '(...).dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'test.exe': Unloaded '(...).dll'
'test.exe': Loaded '(...).dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'test.exe': Unloaded '(...).dll'
```

I would like to know the reason for this. Why is this happening and how to stop it?

Some third party program seems to be attaching itself there somehow. Is there any way to stop it except by deleting this third party program?

Note: the dll name isn't important here so I hided it to prevent offtopic discussion.

Comment: _the dll name isn't important_ ?? Really? This is the DLL that needs to be built with debugging information

Comment: You already asked this question.  You'll have to be patient, repeatedly posting the same question and *removing* essential info doesn't get you an answer faster.  Which is still the same, you are yelling for help in a football stadium when you should be contacting the author of this DLL directly.

Comment: @HansPassant, can you explain why would a third party program try to inject itself into my program? Is it a virus?